# Why the ballon service on Windows KVM guest needs to be restart or manually start can host get real memory usage?

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, openstack, kvm, libvirt

I've installed virtio-win on the Windows guest.

Actually it works fine but one problem is that the service can not be automatically started, if do so, not memory stats can be found in the host.

When I manually started or restarted, the stats will works okay.

How could that happened? Is the problem of virtio-win or mine? I just installed it without any actions :(

Thank you for your help.

Comment: the Windows version is 19, 12R2 and virtio-win version is the latest stable.

Comment: Have you tried a reboot to have changes applied?